# POST request with JSON in Dispatch and Scala

Tags: json, scala, post, scala-dispatch

I'm having trouble making a POST request with a JSON object using Dispatch and Scala.

The POST request works fine for sure since I tested it using curl:

```
~/workspace $ curl -vd 'tracker={"project":"campaign","event":"home","number":"100"}'  http://exampleurl:8145/test
```

and I get a HTTP 200 response as expected

But when I try doing the same using Dispatch library ( http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html ) like so:

```
scala> Http(url("http://exampleurl:8145/test") << "tracker={'project':'campaign','event':'home','number':'100'}" >|)
```

this is what I get:

```
dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response code: 404
Paramerter missing: [tracker] not found
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$when$1.apply(executor.scala:53)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$when$1.apply(executor.scala:50)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$x$2.apply(executor.scala:41)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$x$2.apply(executor.scala:36)
at dispatch.BlockingHttp$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(Http.scala:54)
at dispatch.Http.pack(Http.scala:25)
at dispatch.BlockingHttp$class.execute(Http.scala:53)
at dispatch.Http.execute(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.x(executor.scala:36)
at dispatch.Http.x(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.when(executor.scala:50)
at dispatch.Http.when(Http.scala:21)
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$class.apply(executor.scala:60)
at dispatch.Http.apply(Http.scala:21)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:914)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:546)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:577)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:543)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:694)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:745)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:651)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:542)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:550)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:851)
at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:57)
at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
at sbt.Console.console0$1(Console.scala:23)
at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
```

I'm not sure why it's missing the tracker parameter that I'm trying to pass through.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to post it as a name value pair:

```
Http(url("http://exampleurl:8145/test") << 
  Map("tracker" -> "{'project':'campaign','event':'home','number':'100'}") >|)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about your version of dispatch, but another way to do this (in version 0.11.0, at least) (especially if it is not convenient to mash your data back into a Map) is to explicitly set the the content type, like this:

```
Http(url("http://exampleurl:8145/test").setBody(
     "tracker={'project':'campaign','event':'home','number':'100'}").setHeader(
     "Content-Type", "application/json") OK as.String)
```

NOTE: I removed the ">|" operator (which is from dispatch 0.8.x and ignores the response) with "OK as.String". Feel free to ignore that response string.

This is nice in the case that you are using [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/) with case classes (or just mangling with the AST in general). Then instead of

```
Http(url("http://someplace.com") << someAwfulTransformer(
     myCaseClassOrBigASTbasedThing) OK as.String)
```

you can do this

```
Http(url("http://someplace.com").setBody(
     write(myCaseClassOrBigASTbasedThing)).setHeader(
     "Content-Type", "application/json") OK as.String)
```

Feel free to decorate this with your implicits or helper functions to minimize typing. But the point is that if you have a direct entity to JSON string mapping, you don't need to worry about transforming it back into a Map. In fact, you *shouldn't*.